# Java concurrency confusion

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I've following class

```
class A{

private int id =0;
   public void setMessageId(Message m) {
      synchronized(m) {
        m.setId(id++);
      }
   }
}
```

Can two threads with same instance of class A with DIFFERENT instances of Message enter into the synchronized block at same time and set same id to different instances of message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since the block is synchronized on the message, two threads using two different message instances can enter the synchronized block concurrently, and both get the same ID.

Make the method synchronized, and everything will be fine. Or use an AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You need to synchronize on the object that holds the `id` field (in this case 'A') or some common object.

Comment: can I just synchronize the setMethodId(...) method, since id is only modified in this region.

Answer (score 0):

If you only synchronize on m, then two objects will be able to modify the same instance of A. You need to synchronize on the object that stores the value id.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because you synchronize on different objects.

If all what you need for this purpose it's ID generation better to use java.util.concurrent [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

For example like this:

```
private AtomicInteger counter;

public int getNextUniqueIndex() {
    return counter.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** As the **synchronized lock is on the instance of message**, and then **two thread with different message object can definately access this block at the same time.**

**2.** Even **if they are setting the same instance variable, its like a personal copy which is one per object.**

**3.** Thread **changing the variable** `id` of **one object will Not effect the id of other** object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

The lock object is obtained for the m object which are 2 different objects for each of your threads so yes they can. You will need to obtain a lock which is shared between those 2 and that A class in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because they both have locks to different objects.

One option without self made synchronization at all is to use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
class A{
    private final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

    public void setMessageId(Message m) {
       m.setId(id.incrementAndGet());    
    }
}
```

Method [incrementAndGet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) incerements value by one and returns updated value.